# CSF Unresolved issue

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I began receiving service failures for CSF/LFD once the limit was reached in iptables preventing the service from working properly.

I flushed all iptables rules, and redid by rules using CIDR rather than the individual IPs that were listed and the issue persists.

> Error: The VPS iptables rule limit (numiptent) is too low (1527/1536)
>   - stopping firewall to prevent iptables blocking all connections, at line 1459

This is after restarting CSF, which gave me:

> You have an unresolved error when starting csf. You need to restart
>   csf successfully to remove this warning

CSF still seems to be trying to enforce rules that no longer exists (lists entire chains upon trying to be restarted,only to fail with that error).

Any idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, this was an issue that came as a result of a WHM update that resulted in needing to reinstall CSF. This solved the problem.